# How to monitor laptop temperature?

Tags: 12.04, lubuntu, acpi, temperature, sensors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the CPU temperature?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15832/how-do-i-get-the-cpu-temperature)
>   [No ACPI support for my PC, what can I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127989/no-acpi-support-for-my-pc-what-can-i-do)

After installing `lm-sensors` and runing `sudo sensors-detect` i got the message:

```
Sorry, no sensors were detected.
This is relatively common on laptops, where thermal management is
handled by ACPI rather than the OS.
```

What is to be done in this case? (How to access ACPI?)

I'm in Lubuntu 12.04 on a hp compaq laptop

Comment: @Anwar it's probably a duplicate of this one instead, '[No ACPI support for my PC, what can I do?](http://askubuntu.com/q/127989/12864)' Cipricus, can you look at the answer there and see if that helps please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All sensors-detect does is detect and enable additional sensor drivers if necessary. If you simply run the `sensors` command in the terminal, it should show you the temperature.

Comment: i see there exactly what i see in psensor, which acts like a front for what is in terminal (what app is that?). but can you tell me what line stands for what component?

Comment: I can't tell you which one is which component. It varies across systems, so you'll have to figure it out. You can look in the BIOS setup for your system to see what the temperatures are, and write them down, then see if they match up to what is output by sensors when you boot into the system. Of course, some may be the same, and some may have changed by a degree or two. You'll have to read the lm-sensors docs about how to rename them in the config.

Comment: yes. i tried to figure it out taking into account in relation to what action each temperature variates - http://askubuntu.com/q/167434/47206